# Google Calendar API (v3) - PHP can write but not read?

Tags: php, curl, calendar, google-api, google-calendar-api

I spent all day figuring out the Google Calendar API. I finally managed to insert an event in my Google Calendar but now I cannot seem to get the "list" command working.

The following code **works**:

```
    <?php
    $start = array(
        "dateTime" => $date . "T" . $start_time . ":00",
        "timeZone" => "Europe/Berlin"
    );

    $end = array(
        "dateTime" => $date . "T" . $end_time . ":00",
        "timeZone" => "Europe/Berlin"
    );

    $headerarray = array(
        'Content-type: application/json',
        'Authorization: Bearer ' . $access_token,
        'X-JavaScript-User-Agent: Google APIs Explorer'
    );

    $post_data = array(
        "start"       => $start,
        "end"         => $end,
        "summary"     => $title,
        "description" => $description,
        "key"         => $api_key
    );

    $post_data = json_encode($post_data);

    $url = 'https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars/' . $calendar_id . '/events';

    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPGET, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headerarray);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post_data);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

    $response = curl_exec($ch);
    $response = json_decode($response);
    ?>
```

This piece of code creates a new event in my calendar, so I should have everything set up correctly, right?

However this code does **not** work:

```
    <?php
    $headerarray = array(
        "Authorization: Bearer " . $access_token,
        "X-JavaScript-User-Agent: Google APIs Explorer"
    );

    $url = 'https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars/' . $calendar_id . '/events?key=' . $api_key;

    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headerarray);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

    $response = curl_exec($ch);
    $response = json_decode($response);
    ?>
```

In this case I get the following response: `Access Not Configured. Please use Google Developers Console to activate the API for your project.`

But that is not the case. I configured the access correctly, or else I would not be able to insert events into the calendar, right? Maybe I am not using cURL right?

This is the reference for the list function: https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/events/list

What am I not seeing here? Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: Well, nevermind! It works now. I don't know why. I don't know why it didn't work before. I did not make any changes and it suddenly worked. -.-

Comment: why are you using `curlopt_httpget` and `curlopt_post` in you're first example?

Answer (score 1):

Try this one :

- Go to : https://console.developers.google.com
- select project
- go to: APIs and auth
- Activate calendar api

Answer (score 1):

I spent my whole day to create the event , I'm able to fetch the event

here is my code to fetch data from google oauth and I am using the codeigniter framework.

```
<?php
    // product_config
     $config['google_id'] = '';
     $config['google_secret'] = '';

    // oauth file
    function get_calendar_events(OAuth2_Token_Access $token){
        try{

            $max_results = 250;
            $url = 'https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars/primary/events?showDeleted=false&$orderBy=email&maxResults='.$max_results.'&alt=json&v=3.0&oauth_token='.$token->access_token;
            $google_events = json_decode(file_get_contents($url), true);

            return $google_events;

        }catch (Exception $e) {
            // Exception
        }
    }

    /*** Controller ***/
    function myCalendar() {
        try {
            $events = array();
            $provider_name = 'google';
            $provider = $this->oauth2->provider($provider_name, array(
                    'id' => $this->config->item($provider_name.'_id', 'product_config'),
                    'secret' => $this->config->item($provider_name.'_secret', 'product_config'),
                    'scopes' =>  array('https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar',
                                'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar.readonly')
            ));

            if (!$this->input->get('code')){ // access authorizing
                // By sending no options it'll come back here
                $provider->authorize();
            }else{
                // Get the Token
                $token = $provider->access($this->input->get('code'));
                $events  = $provider->get_calendar_events($token);
        }catch (Exception $e) {
            // Exception
        }
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public function create_calendar_event(OAuth2_Token_Access $token,$description, $leaveDate , $toLeaveDate,$title, $stime, $etime ){
    try {

        $title = $title;

        //$start_time = '00:00'; $end_time = '23:59';
        $start_time = $stime;
        $end_time = $etime;
        $timezone       = 'Asia/Kolkata';

        $start = array(
            "dateTime" => $leaveDate . "T" . $start_time . ":00",
            "timeZone" => $timezone
        );

        $end = array(
            "dateTime" => $toLeaveDate . "T" . $end_time . ":00",
            "timeZone" => $timezone
        );

        $headerarray = array(
            'Content-type: application/json',
            'Authorization: Bearer ' . $token->access_token,
            'X-JavaScript-User-Agent: Google APIs Explorer'
        );

        $post_data = array(
                "start"       => $start,
                "end"         => $end,
                "summary"     => $title,
                "description" => $description,
                "key"         => $this->api_key
        );

        $post_data = json_encode($post_data);
        $calendar_id = 'primary';

        $url = 'https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars/' . $calendar_id . '/events';

        $result = $this->NewcurlRequest($url, $headerarray, $post_data);

    }catch(Exception $e){
        // Exception
    }
}
public function NewcurlRequest($url,$headerarray,$post_data, $curl_call = true){
    try{

        $ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
        //curl_setopt($ch, curlopt_post, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headerarray);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post_data);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

        $response = curl_exec($ch);
        curl_close($ch);

        return $response;
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        return $e;
    }
}
```